# Why does Ruby change variables outside the scope of a class?

Tags: ruby

Given the following set of classes:

```
class Cat
  def initialize(value)
     @value = value
  end

  def speak
     @value.pop()
     puts @value
  end
end

speak = ["Meow","Hiss","Chirp"]

cat = Cat.new(speak)
cat.speak
puts speak

class Dog
  def initialize(value)
     @value = value
  end

  def speak
     @value.sub!("Bark", "Woof")
     puts @value
  end
end

speak = "Bark!"

dog = Dog.new(speak)
dog.speak
puts speak
```

I would expect the following output to be:

```
Meow
Hiss
Meow
Hiss
Chirp
Woof!
Bark!
```

And it is if I provide `@value = value.dup` but it doesn't feel Ruby'esque

However the output I receive is:

```
Meow
Hiss
Meow
Hiss
Woof!
Woof!
```

Is this the expected behavior of Ruby? Should a class be able to modify the argument originator? I know that setting `@value = value` will return identical object_id's for both `@value` and `value` however, if I set `@value = 'somethingelse'` shouldn't it create a new object instead of changing the original object?

Comment: This is the expected behavior. In Ruby all objects (except primitives like Fixnum) are passed by reference. Ruby does not make a copy of an object when you pass it to a method.

Comment: I recently cut my hair. Now, some people know me as "Jörg", and some people know me as "Mr. Mittag". My hairdresser knows me as "Mr. Mittag". However, even though he only cut "Mr. Mittag"'s hair, people who know me as "Jörg" also observe my hair having been cut. It's irrelevant by what name you call me. What is relevant is that *I* changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. And no, if you want to assign a new object then you need to explicitly call `dup` or `clone` on the object:

```
@value = value.dup
```

Read about the difference between [`clone` and `dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-dup-label-on+dup+vs+clone) in the Ruby docs.

Comment: Yeah, this is one of the important Ruby principles: Don't mangle things you're given unless you can rightly assume ownership over them. If you need to make alterations to something passed in by an argument, make a copy.